# SQL query removing duplicates & pulling random results

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct

So I have searched around for an answer, but I am unable to find one for this conundrum I am in. I have a query that will successfully pull back X amount of random accounts or distinct accounts. However, I would like to combine these two together in to one SQL query, not two. So I will be pulling back transaction data from a specific time range to where I need to pull back no duplicate accounts and then out of those non-duplicate accounts, pick X random accounts from that list.

Currently, this is the query I have:

```
SELECT TOP 75 [Account]
FROM table
ORDER BY NEWid()
```

I have tried putting DISTINCT in there, but I can't find the right place to put it.

Now, yes I know I can do all of this in excel. However, in order to automate and expedite the process, I would like to accomplish this through SQL.

Comment: how is this random?

Comment: You are right. I did forget a line of code. That would be the order by newid(). Thanks for pointing this out. OP edited.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you don't say what platform you are using except TOP X is MSSQL

I guess you want this

```
SELECT TOP 25 *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT [Account]
  FROM table
) x
```

However, I don't think any platform returns results in a random order when you use DISTINCT -- think about it... you have to sort to make it distinct.

So you can make it a random order...

```
SELECT TOP 25 *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT [Account]
  FROM table
) x
ORDER BY newid()
```

However this will be slow -- if it is just that you don't care about the order then don't use this randomizing trick.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I don't care about the order, no. That is not a big deal to me.

However, I have tried your above code, and it does work (which I am very happy for). I just have one more small little issue popping up and I am not sure why. Here is the code currently:

SELECT TOP 75 [Account]
  FROM (
  Select distinct [Account]
  FROM table
  where TransDate>='2017-5-1') x
  order by NEWid()


The issue is happening in the "where" statement. I need to isolate the data being pulled back based on a specific date range. Suggestions on that? Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, so looks like the issue was I had an extra parenthesis added. It is now functioning correctly. Thanks for the answer. :)